# pandas json.loads(), printing \u3000 instead of japanese value

Tags: python, json, pandas, ascii

Below is the code snippet:

```
import json

x = """{
        "phone": "06-1234-5687",
        "name": "福井整科クリック　医"
    }"""
 
y = json.loads(x)
print(y)
# output looks like this: {'phone': '06-1234-5687', 'name': '福井整科クリック\u3000医'}
```

how to print original value instead of \u3000.
I didn't find any feasible options available with json.loads() function.

Comment: It is how Python choose to print a dictionary, `for v in y.values(): print(v)` prints the whitespace just fine.

Comment: Are you sure about original value? Probably your editor will show the escape code? You should use `encode()` inside `print`, and e.g. ASCII or Latin1, and then use option about escaping the codes outside encoding